# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'appendTo'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I badly need your help. I am having an error which is **0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'appendTo'** Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Open_Sans_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Open_Sans_Light_300.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Open_Sans_Semibold_600.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tms-0.3.js"></script> //error appears on this 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tms_presets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/FF-cash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>


bannersFu:function(){
        var _=this
        if(_.banners===false)
            return false
        _.banners=[]
        $(_.items,_.me).each(function(i){
            var tmp
            _.banners[i]=(tmp=$('.'+_.bannerCl,this)).length?tmp:false
        })
        _.bannerShow(_.banner=_.banners[_.show].appendTo(_.me))//This is where the error comes
    },
```

Your answers and opinion will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: most likely `_.banners[_.show]` isn't a jQuery object. (in your code it can be either a jQuery object or false. when it is false, it will fail.)

Comment: @KevinB: Or `undefined`, if `i` never has whatever value is in `_.show`.

Comment: Is it `=` or `==` in that line?

Comment: I would really, really not like to be the person who has to maintain that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `appendTo` on `_.banners[_.show]`. From your code, it's entirely possible that `_.banners[_.show]` could be either `false` or `undefined`, not a jQuery object.

If in the `each` loop, if `i` is ever equal to whatever is in `_.show`, then `_.banners[_.show]` will be either a jQuery object (with an `appendTo` method), or `false` (which doesn't have one), depending on whether `$('.'+_.bannerCl,this)` found any elements.

If `i` is never equal to `_.show`, then `_.banners[_.show]` will be `undefined`, which doesn't have an `appendTo` method.

The only way to figure out exactly what's going on is old-fashioned debugging: Use the debugger built into your browser, sets breakpoints, single-step through the code, inspect variables at various points in the debugger's display of variables, etc., etc.

Comment: Ok sir, I'll try your suggestion now.