# JQuery menu method on ul throws "0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, menu, html-lists

I have this weird problem.  When I have the following code doe a JQuery menu in its own html file – it works as expected.  However, if I put it in my Master page which is used in ASP .Net application, the line of code

```
$("#testMenu").menu();
```

throws the exception:

***0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method***

I want to make clear that it is not a dumb copy and paste.   matches in both files.  in the master page has more scripts and CSS links.  But everything listed below exists in the master page.

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#testMenu").menu();
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .ui-menu {
            width: 150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="testMenu" class="ui-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3-3-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3-3-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3-3-3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3-3-4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3-3-5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what may be the problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'appendTo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604052/0x800a01b6-javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method)

I.E : add a `document.ready` to ensure `#testmenu` is not undefined or null